# PyQt4: Making toggle radio button which opens different combo boxes on the same window

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt4

I am creating a feature within a QTabWidget which will:

1. Allow the user to toggle a radio button with which analysis the individual wants to execute (2 options).
2. Depending on which radio button is toggled, add certain comboboxes below the radio buttons.
3. Create dependency between comboboxes.
4. When the 'Reset Parameters' pushbutton is pushed, all of the parameters are reset.

I was able to make the 'Reset Parameters' work for the most part in which it untoggles both of the radio buttons & the dependency between the comboboxes works on its own. But I am not sure how to define the function which can add the selected comboboxes to the previously defined grid layout. Also, not sure where/why the awkward drop down menu is coming from by the tab name.

The code was inputted into an iPython notebook from Anaconda using Python 2.7.

```
#7.5.2016 making toggle switches

import sys
import webbrowser
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Plastique'))

class BeginExplorerWidget(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BeginExplorerWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50,50,800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Explorer")

        #Defining items inside the tabs

        #tab 1: ProQinase Cancer Cell Line Explorer
        button = QtGui.QPushButton("Reset parameters")
        button.clicked.connect(self.my_method)        
        self.rad1 = QtGui.QRadioButton("Explore Individual Cell Lines")
        self.rad1.toggled.connect(lambda: self.btnstate(self.rad1))
        self.rad2 = QtGui.QRadioButton("Cell Line Correlation")
        self.rad2.toggled.connect(lambda: self.btnstate(self.rad2))

        #opens if rad1 on
        self.combo1 = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.list1 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
        self.combo1.addItems(QtCore.QStringList(self.list1))
        self.combo1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.changeindexcombo1)
        self.combo2 = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.list2 =[['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']]
        self.combo2.addItems(QtCore.QStringList(self.list2[0]))

        #opens if rad2 on
        self.comboA = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.listA = ['CPQ #', 'CCLE #']
        self.comboA.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.changeindexcomboA)
        self.comboB = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.listB = [['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'], ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']]
        self.comboC = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.listC = ['CPQ #', 'CCLE #']
        self.comboC.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.changeindexcomboC)
        self.comboD = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.listD = [['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'], ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']]

        tab1 = QtGui.QWidget()  

        #layouts:        
        #tab 1: ProQinase Cancer Cell Line Explorer
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button, 0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.rad1, 0,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.rad2, 0,2)
        tab1.setLayout(layout)

        self.group = QtGui.QButtonGroup()
        self.group.addButton(self.rad1)
        self.group.addButton(self.rad2)

        #adding tabs to the QtGui.QTabWidget
        self.addTab(tab1,"ProQinase Cancer Cell Lines")

        self.show()

    def my_method(self):
        self.group.setExclusive(False)
        self.rad1.setChecked(False)
        self.rad2.setChecked(False)
        self.group.setExclusive(True)

    def btnstate(self, rad):
        if rad.text() == "Explore Individual Cell Lines":
            self.tab1.addWidget(self.combo1, 1, 1)
            self.tab1.addWidget(self.combo2, 1, 2)       
        if rad.text() == "Cell Line Correlation":
            #layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
            self.tab1.addWidget(self.comboA, 1, 1)
            self.tab1.addWidget(self.comboB, 1, 2)
            self.tab1.addWidget(self.comboC, 2, 1)
            self.tab1.addWidget(self.comboD, 2, 2)
            #tab1.setlayout(layout)

    def changeindexcombo1(self, ind):
        self.combo2.clear()
        self.combo2.addItems(QtCore.QStringList(self.list2[ind]))

    def changeindexcomboA(self, ind):
        self.comboB.clear()
        self.comboB.addItems(QtCore.QStringList(self.list2[ind]))

    def changeindexcomboC(self, ind):
        self.comboD.clear()
        self.comboD.addItems(QtCore.QStringList(self.list2[ind]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = BeginExplorerWidget()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```