# PyQt4: Conditionally populating a preset 3x3 gridlayout

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4

I want to define a preset 3x3 grid layout within a qwidget, which will become conditionally populated if a certain radio button within one of the squares in the grid is selected. How could this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the QWidget you are populating? Are there 9 different radio buttons in the 3x3 grid?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. The first row has a pushbutton and 2 radio buttons. If I select one radio button underneath will appear certain comboboxes and if I select the other radiobutton, other comboboxes will appear. This question was asked in support of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210976/pyqt4-making-toggle-radio-button-which-opens-different-combo-boxes-on-the-same I am having a tough time knowing the best way of approaching this problem.